# Is it possible to attach a React-Native webview container to the background, so that it does not move?

Tags: react-native, webview

I have a React native webview container, and I'd like it to stay in place when scrolling past the end of the view, at the moment the entire view moves and whitespace is revealed. Is this possible?

Comment: can you share what you have done so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was trying a while ago something like that, and I found a workaround, and probably it would help you.

There is a prop on `<WebView/>` called [injectedJavaScript](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/0.59/webview#injectedjavascript) that will be injected into the web page when the view loads, so then you can add this code:

```js
document.createElement('meta');
meta.setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0');
meta.setAttribute('name', 'viewport');
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta);
```

and then add it to your project. Check the snack I created [snack.expo.io/@abranhe/stackoverflow-56858778](https://snack.expo.io/@abranhe/stackoverflow-56858778)

[image]

The source code:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { View, WebView, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

const disableZoom = `const meta = document.createElement('meta');
                    meta.setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0');
                    meta.setAttribute('name', 'viewport');
                    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta);`;

export default () => (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <View style={styles.webview}>
      <WebView
        useWebKit={true}
        source={{ url: 'https://google.com' }}
        injectedJavaScript={disableZoom}
        javaScriptEnabled={true}
        domStorageEnabled={true}
      />
    </View>
  </View>
);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    marginTop: 30,
  },
  webview: {
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
  },
});
```

Hope this works for you!